# Elementor contact form doesn’t work: “Oops! I cannot send this email!”

Tags: plugins, errors, nginx, contact

My contact page has the default Elementor contact form, but it doesn’t work.

I really don’t know where could be the problem. Could you help me?

Edit:

I fixed by installing sendmail (needed by Elementor contact form) following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/php-mail-function-enable

Comment: I don't think WordPress itself generates that specific error, so it's probably something in Elementor. Do you have any error logs, e.g. from nginx or a separate PHP log that you can look at? There might be something in there.

Comment: @Rup thanks for anwer. I looked at /var/log/nginx/error.log but nothing shows up when I use my contact form and receive that error. I also looked at /var/log/php7.4-fpm.log